# How to scroll down and display section on the same page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm developing a one-page website, when user clicks a particular button it should be scrolled down to another section on the page.

Can anyone guide me how to do that?

Comment: see this example (https://codepen.io/magglomag/pen/RPGgJG) 2) (https://codepen.io/ajayadav09/pen/KBFGh)

Comment: Try making the section at least as tall as the browser window, i.e. 100vh.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! But this method increasing gaps between other section.

Answer (score 0):

I think the CSS property `scroll-padding-top` is your answer.

Comment: Thank you soo much for the reply. Do i need to add this property in my #readmore section or to my button code?

Comment: In the readmore section. Also u could add it to the root if it is what you want for other sections too.

Answer (score 0):

### You have different options to solve this

The first approach is to use only HTML to scroll to the element with an specific `id`

```css
html{height:3000px;scroll-behavior: smooth;}
#readmore{position:absolute; top:2000px;}
```

```html
<a href="#readmore">Scroll down</a>
<h1 id="readmore">
Read More
</h1>
```

The second approach is to use `scrollIntoView` method, which scrolls the specified element into the visible area of the browser window.

```js
const element = document.getElementById("readmore");

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
  element.scrollIntoView();
})
```

```css
html{height:3000px;scroll-behavior: smooth;}
#readmore{position:absolute; top:2000px;}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Scroll down</button>
<h1 id="readmore">
Read More
</h1>
```

The third approach is to hard code the specific location where I would like to scroll, in this case I set it to `2000px` (height)

```js
const element = document.getElementById("readmore");

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 2000);
})
```

```css
html{height:3000px;scroll-behavior: smooth;}
#readmore{position:absolute; top:2000px;}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Scroll down</button>
<h1 id="readmore">
Read More
</h1>
```